# How to query MobileServiceSQLiteStore on Azure

Tags: sqlite, azure, join, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have Azure Mobile Data sync setup to Sync a db on Azure with a .net application.

I am using the SQLLite backend.

How do I issue a query on the local sqllite database?

I can't figure out how to do a simple join query "Select * from table1, table2 where table1.id=table2.id"

Answer (score 2):

Download any sqlite database manager to run query against sqlite database.
Sqlite expert is an awesome free tool. http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html. Almost all normal SQL queries will work in sqlite database too.